# what is pmbx_context that gets injected into input fields etc

Tags: html, google-chrome

Strangely enough I have searched on google and here and can't find any info on it, but in chrome, when I view source or element this is being injected into form fields, html tag etc `pmbx_context="odd looking random number"` - with a random looking number in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is caused by the Chrome plugin `Bitdefender Wallet`, or could be caused by any similar plugin. You can try to disable your recently installed plugins to see what causes it.

Comment: Yea it seems to have gone now that I have disabled Bitdefender Wallet. Thanks